# Why does this code throw an exception?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,j;
        int count = 0;
        int test=scan.nextInt();
        String[] con=new String[test];
        while(test>0)
         {i=scan.nextInt();
         j=scan.nextInt();

             for(int k=i;k<=j;k++)
             if(prime(k))
//***********the line below where i am getting nullpointer exception
            con[count].concat(k+"\n");


    test--;count++;}

    for( i=0;i<con.length;i++)
        System.out.printf("%s\n",con[i]);
    }



    private static boolean prime(int k) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(k==2)
            return true;
        if(k%2==0)
            return false;
        for(int l=3;l<=Math.sqrt(k);l=l+2)
        if(k%l==0)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

please somebody help me that how to get rid from this exception.

Comment: where do you populate your con array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String[] con=new String[test];` creates a new `String` array with `test` elements, and assigns it to `con`. However, *this does not create any `String` objects at all* - you have simply created an array where all elements are `null`. You must ensure that `con[count]` actually refers to a `String` before calling `concat()` on it; you can either do this by checking if it is `null` and assigning `""` to it before calling `concat()`, or you can have a separate loop that puts an empty string into each element of `con`.

By the way: `concat()` does *not* modify the `String` you call it on; it creates a new `String` and returns it, but you don't do anything with the return value, so it gets thrown away. You should use `+=` instead (which also creates a new `String`, but it will assign the new `String` to the array element).

Answer (score 1):

Since you'r getting NullPointerException here,

```
 con[count].concat(k+"\n");
```

it means that the value of `con[count]` is `null` and you are trying to call `.concat( )` on the null instance.

Here, `con[]` is *not initialized*, so it takes `null` by default. You need to initialize the elements of `con[]` array i.e say to `""` and then try calling the concat method.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing each element of con[]

new String[] gives you an array of null string references.  You have to set them to the empty string if you want your code to work.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
String[] con=new String[test];
```

you create a new String-array of length `test`. The elements in this array, however, start out being `null`. Therefore, you cannot call `concat` on them before initializing them to a string.

This means, you should initialize the string to the empty string, `""`, before doing calling `concat` on it.

In addition, strings are immutable, so [`concat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29) produces a new String, rather than modifying the existing one, so you need to save the result.

This means, you all in all want something like:

```
while(test>0) {
    i=scan.nextInt();
    j=scan.nextInt();
    con[count] = ""; // Initialize con[count]


    for(int k=i;k<=j;k++) {
        if(prime(k)) {
            con[count] = con[count].concat(k+"\n");
        }
    }

    test--;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like conc[count] is null, if that's where you're getting a NullPointerException.
You should initialize it with a value.